# Can I use import to read a JSON file in a Next.js 13 API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm working with Next.js 13 and utilizing the App Router feature. Currently, I have an API route that reads a file from a resources folder, specifically a language folder. Here's the structure of my API:

```
// app/api/file/[lang]/write/route.ts

import { APIResponseType } from '@/models/api/response';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

type Params = {
  params: {
    lang: string;
  };
};

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params: { lang } }: Params) {
  const data = await import(`../../../../../languages/${lang}.json`);
  return NextResponse.json<APIResponseType>({
    message: 'Get language successfully',
    data: data
  });
}
```

I've tested this API, and it's working as expected.

However, I'm curious if there's a more efficient or recommended approach for reading files from the Next.js resources directory. Any insights or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Updated, I see the path is so complex and hard to read. So I edit the `tsconfig.json` and a new settings to `paths` property:
` "@/languages/*": ["./languages/*"]`

And change line import in api to `const { default: data } = await import(`@/languages/${lang}.json`);`. I have tested it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use resolve function in `path` module like this.

```
import path from 'path';

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params: { lang } }: Params) {
  const languageFilePath = path.resolve('resources', 'languages', `${lang}.json`);
  const data = await import(languageFilePath);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes the code more readable.

Comment: thanks for your reply, feel free to ask to me, I will do my best.